# nativescript and swagger-client

Tags: swagger, nativescript

How to use swagger-client in nativescript?

I have installed swagger-client module in nativescript project and when I require it the following error occurs:

```
JS ERROR Error: Could not find module 'tty'.
```

I guess module is missing from nativescript, but is there way to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this very moment, NativeScript is not supporting **tty**. 
This is logged as a feature request [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/195)

Comment: That's a bummer. Just started to like nativescript.

Comment: `tty` is not even provided by npm at this moment https://www.npmjs.com/package/tty  and look here https://github.com/npm/security-holder/issues/1